# Can pandas read_csv finish gracefully when no file is found?

Tags: python, pandas

When I search for pandas's read_csv function when no file is found I find many question asking "why is my file not found if it exists?"

My question is different. I know the file does not exist.
So when I call `read_csv` I get a FileNotFoundError.

I know I can put a try except to catch the error, but is there a graceful way to indicate the function that I don't want an error, just for example return an empty value or none?

Comment: No, there is no graceful option implemented for the function. You need to handle the error one way or the other. You can implement a `MaybeFilePath` class in your program similar to [maybe types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#An_example:_Maybe) in functional programming that behaves like a file if the filepath exists or an empty buffer if it doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

The job of [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) is to read a file, not check if it exists or not. You can do that using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)'s `Path`. You can pass a `Path` object t `read_csv` instead of a string too, which means you can do this:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

file=Path("path/to/file.csv")

if file.exists():
    df=pd.read_csv(file)
    ...
```

You'll have to decide what to do if the path doesn't exist. The simplest option would be to just not proceed with processing.

It's not enough to return an empty Dataframe if the calling code expects it to have specific columns. You'll have to create a dataframe with those columns but no rows.

```
if file.exists():
    df=pd.read_csv(file)
    ...
    return df
else:
    column_names = ["ColA", "ColB", "ColC"]
    return pd.DataFrame(column_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

"Exception Handling
When an error occurs, or exception as we call it, Python will normally stop and generate an error message.

These exceptions can be handled using the try statement:"

Since you don't want to stop your function in my opinion the only way is to use try except.

In your case this would be something like this :

```
def function ()
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv('csv name')
    except:
        print("An exception occurred")
    else: 
        df = pd.read_csv('csv name')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch an error to return an empty dataframe with [**`pandas.DataFrame`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor.

```
try:
    df = pd.read_csv('a_non_exsiting_file.csv')

except FileNotFoundError:
    df = pd.DataFrame()
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```